# How to pass prop to react router component via NavDropdown.Item link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a dropdown list dynamically, and I need it to pass props to the route component. I tried the below technique which I found here on SO, to no avail. Any help much appreciated.

**The Route and Link Component (With attempted testprop prop)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AlphaRun from './components/alpha-run/AlphaRun.jsx';

const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

render(
  <div className="App container">
    <Router>
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
            <Navbar.Brand href="/">OfficeX</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <NavDropdown title="Class Lists" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                        <NavDropdown.Item testprop="test" href="/alpharun">Alpha Run</NavDropdown.Item>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>

        <Switch>
            <Route path="/alpharun" render={
                (props) => <AlphaRun {...props} />
            } />
        </Switch>
    </Router>    
</div>
, rootEl);
```

As you can see, I attempted to pass `testprop` in the `NavDropdown.Item` link. However, this doesn't work and the prop is undefined in the `AlphaRun` component.

In the `AlphaRun` component, I'm simply using an `alert` in `componentDidMount` to test for the prop:

```
componentDidMount() {
    alert(this.props.testprop);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NavDropdown.Item` is just a React component, so giving it any props wont pass any data to the `Route`. If you want to transfer information into the route props, you've got two real options:

## 1: Use a Route with a path containing a url parameter

For example, this could be `path="/alpharun/:id"`. Then, you'd use `props.match.params.id` to access the id. To go to this route, you'd use `<Link to="/alpharun/foo"></Link>`

## 2: Use a link with location state:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "alpharun", state: { id: 3 }}}></Link>
```

This could be accessed from the Route with `props.location.state`.

---

The difference in the two approaches is that with location state you won't be able to access it directly from the URL bar in the browser.

Comment: Yeah that did it. I tried option 1 at one point, but I was missing the params in `this.match.params`. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how React works. I'm not sure what those NavItems are but they don't render any React components themselves.

`Route` however does with the `render` prop and it renders AlphaRun which is where you want to put your props that you want to pass on.

```js
<Route path="/alpharun" render={() =>
  <AlphaRun prop='here' testprop='test'/>
} />
```

Now when you go to `/alpharun` URI it should render that react component.

Comment: Yeah... I'm aware of how easy it is to pass a prop directly into a component. As I said in the OP, I need the link created by `NavDropdown.Item` to pass a parameter into the component. Much as a querystring can be used to pass a parameter into a page. Very common occurrence.